# Remove the large spacing between before and after discrete x-axis values in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
L <- c(215,200,186,237,220,206,257,240,226,276,260,243,297,280,263,318,300,283)
UG <- c(rep("UG-84",3),rep("UG-92",3),rep("UG-100",3),rep("UG-108",3),rep("UG-116",3),rep("UG-124",3))
S <- c(rep(c(9,12,15),3))
figure2 <- data.frame(S=S,UG=UG,L=L)
```

When I try to plot it, I get a large spacing before and after the factor x-axis values (I want to show these exact numbers on the x-axis which is why i did not go with continuous)

```
ggplot(figure2) +
aes(x = as.factor(S), y = L, colour = UG, group = UG) + geom_line(size = 1L) +
geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = L), hjust = 0.5,  vjust = -1) + 
scale_color_hue() + theme_classic() +
labs(x = "Girder Spacing (ft)", y = "Max Span Length (ft)", 
  title = "Ultra-Girder Estimated Maximum Span Lengths", 
  subtitle = "Designed with 22 ksi UHPC", 
  caption = "Designed Based on AASHTO LRFD Specifications and The Ultra-High Performance Fiber-Reinforced Concretes—Interim Recommendations", 
  color = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(40,0,5,0), 
      face = "bold", size = 18), 
      plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(5,0,45,0), size = 10),
      axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,20,0,0)),
      axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(20,0,40,0)),
      legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "right5", 
      legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
      legend.box.margin = margin(5,10,0,5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `expand` inside `scale_x_discrete()` option:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
L <- c(215,200,186,237,220,206,257,240,226,276,260,243,297,280,263,318,300,283)
UG <- c(rep("UG-84",3),rep("UG-92",3),rep("UG-100",3),rep("UG-108",3),rep("UG-116",3),rep("UG-124",3))
S <- c(rep(c(9,12,15),3))
figure2 <- data.frame(S=S,UG=UG,L=L)
#Plot
ggplot(figure2) +
  aes(x = as.factor(S), y = L, colour = UG, group = UG) + geom_line(size = 1L) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.01,0))+
  scale_color_hue() + theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Girder Spacing (ft)", y = "Max Span Length (ft)", 
       title = "Ultra-Girder Estimated Maximum Span Lengths", 
       subtitle = "Designed with 22 ksi UHPC", 
       caption = "Designed Based on AASHTO LRFD Specifications and The Ultra-High Performance Fiber-Reinforced Concretes—Interim Recommendations", 
       color = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(40,0,5,0), 
                                                                  face = "bold", size = 18), 
                                        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(5,0,45,0), size = 10),
                                        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,20,0,0)),
                                        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(20,0,40,0)),
                                        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "right5", 
                                        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
                                        legend.box.margin = margin(5,10,0,5))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a continuous scale and specify the axis breaks that you want:

```
ggplot(figure2) +
 ## remove the factor() around S
 aes(x = S, y = L, colour = UG, group = UG) + geom_line(size = 1L) +
 ## specify breaks
 ## you could also use `breaks = unique(figure2$S)` if you want it based directly on the data
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(9, 12, 15)) +
 scale_color_hue() +
 theme_classic() + ...
 ### ... all the same labs and theme as in your question
```

[image]

You could remove the padding from the discrete scale with `scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0, 0))` (or completely remove the padding from the continuous scale by giving `expand = expansion(0, 0)` as an argument to `scale_x_continuous)`), but it's a bad habit to use discrete scales on continuous data. If your data point didn't happen to be evenly spaced, you'd end up distorting the data by using a discrete scale.